# Redirect warnings & error messages produced by assertions into the logfile [R]

Tags: r, logging, assertion

I am writing a function which would create a logfile along the output. The logfile is supposed to contain the info whether the data processing was finished successfully or not (and why is that be).

I know how to display custom error/warning messages using tryCatch (and I use this function IRL). However I do not know how to deal with the messages produced by assertions. I use assertthat & assertive for validation of arguments passed to the function.

I would like to divert (sink?) the assertthat output to the logfile if the argument is missing or does not meet the requirements (so the logfile would inform why the function finished unsuccessfully).

For instance, I would like to have a following info within the logfile: "Function finished unsuccessfully because (assertion msg)". Does anyone know how to do it?

Here is a dummy function which does nothing spectacular, it serves just as a simple reprex:

```
   example_function <- function(input_vec, input_num, save_dir){
      
      cat(paste0('[', as.character(Sys.time()), '] ', 'Pipeline initialized','\n','\n'))
      
      # Create a log file
      if (dir.exists(file.path(save_dir))) {
        log_filename <- paste0(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"), "_example_function.log", sep = "")
        log_filepath <- file.path(save_dir, log_filename, fsep = .Platform$file.sep)
        log_file <- file(log_filepath, open = "a")
        sink(log_file, append=TRUE, split = TRUE, type='output')
        on.exit(sink(file=NULL, type = 'output'))
      }
      
      #Show console message
      cat(paste0('Hello there!','\n', '\n', sep = ""))
      
       # Handle if save dir does not exist
      if (!dir.exists(file.path(save_dir))) {
        cat(paste0('[', as.character(Sys.time()), '] ', 'Defined save directory does not exist. Creating...','\n', sep=''))
        tryCatch({dir.create(file.path(save_dir, fsep = .Platform$file.sep))
          cat('Done!\n')
        },
        error=function(e){
          cat(paste0('[', as.character(Sys.time()), '] ', 'Failed to create the save dir. Results will be stored in the current working directory.\n', sep=''))
          save_dir <- getwd()
        })
        log_filename <- paste0(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"), "_example_function.log", sep = "")
        log_filepath <- file.path(save_dir, log_filename, fsep = .Platform$file.sep)
        log_file <- file(log_filepath, open = "a")
        sink(log_file, append=TRUE, split = TRUE, type='output')
        on.exit(sink(file=NULL, type = 'output'))
      }
    
      # Assertions
      if (missing(input_vec)) {
        stop("An input_vec is missing. ", call. =FALSE)
      }
    
      if (missing(input_num)) {
        stop("An input_num is missing.", call. =FALSE)
      }
    
      if (missing(save_dir)) {
        stop("A save dir is missing. ", call. =FALSE)
      }
    
      assertthat::assert_that(assertive::is_numeric(input_vec), 
                              msg=paste0("Input vec must be numeric."))
      assertthat::assert_that(assertive::is_numeric(input_num), 
                              msg=paste0("Input vec must be numeric."))
      assertthat::assert_that(assertive::is_character(save_dir),
                              msg = paste0("Path to output files is not a character string."))
      
      
      #just a dummy thing for reprex
      output <- input_vec*input_num
    
    
      #display console messages
      cat(paste0('[', as.character(Sys.time()), '] ','Function finished','\n'))
      cat(paste0('[', as.character(Sys.time()), '] ','A logfile is stored in: ','\n'))
      cat(paste0('  ', log_filepath, '\n'))
    
      # close logfile connection
      on.exit(close(log_file))
      
      
      return(output)
    }
```

And here is some dummy input:

```
input_vec <- c(1:100) 
input_num <- 14

test <- example_function(input_vec = input_vec, input_num = input_num, save_dir =getwd())
```

Currently, the given example does not allow to produce a logfile containing error info produced by assertions.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

I am posting this solution (may be not the neattiest, but it works) because I think it might be useful (there are some other questions regarding logging to a file in R, some of them remain unanswered etc.).

### assertions created with stop() function:

Using the reprex code from the above question. One needs to switch this:

```
   if (missing(input_vec)) {
    stop("An input_vec is missing. ", call. =FALSE)
  }
```

To this:

```
  if (missing(input_vec)) {
    sink(log_file, type='message')
    cat(paste0('[', as.character(Sys.time()), '] ','Function encountered an error. Aborted.\n'))
    on.exit(sink())
    stop("An input_vec is missing. ", call. =FALSE)
  }
```

And use similar syntax in the case of the other similar assertions.

### assertions created with assertthat & assertive

Once more going back to reprex. In this scenario, enclosing conditions within sink() on/off connection works perfectly fine.

```
 sink(log_file, append=TRUE, split = F, type='message')
  assertthat::assert_that(assertive::is_numeric(input_vec), 
                          msg=paste0("Input vec must be numeric."))
  assertthat::assert_that(assertive::is_numeric(input_num), 
                          msg=paste0("Input num must be numeric."))
  assertthat::assert_that(assertive::is_character(save_dir),
                          msg = paste0("Path to output files is not a character string."))
  sink(type='message')
```

I made two big mistakes, which prompted me to ask a question on SO. First, I was trying to sink() the assertion with stop() function outside the condition brackets, which resulted in an empty log (without the error message). Second, regarding assertthat, I tried to put the sink() function inside the assert_that function call, which also was inappropriate. Hadley Wickham's book on advanced R gave me hint how to solve this.